# Position changed when changing the anchorpoint of the (sprite) node

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, sprite-kit, anchorpoint

I am adding the main node and the child nodes to it.
All nodes should be rotating from a variable anchorpoint.

So when I change the anchorpoint of the main node, the distance between the child nodes and the main nodes is being changed(the distance between the childnodes remain the same).

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

EDIT: 6-5-2015

[image]

Here I draw my situation. The anchorpoint of the Main piece is (0.5, 0.5). So when I change the zrotation the whole road will turn around the main part. Than I change the anchorpoint to the second piece(child) so the anchorpoint of the main part becomes (0.5, 1.5). But when I do this the main part moves downwards and I still don't have the rotation point I want..

How can I do this?

Comment: When you change anchor point that means you are changing the drawing position of any node. When you are changing the anchor point change the position accordingly or you can set anchor point before setting position.

Comment: After EDIT: help please?

Comment: Why are you changing the anchor point every time. You can use other animation to rotate.

Comment: How? a car is driving the road and the road should be rotated around the point where the car is at that moment.

Comment: I can not say how? because its depend upon your game logic. But I will suggest if you playing with anchor points than you have to handle the position respectively.

Comment: When I change the position.y of the main piece, the distance between the main piece and child pieces gets bigger, but the position of the road remains the same. Can you suggest some animations I can use to rotate a node around a specific point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77110/discussion-between-sdd-and-vijay-masiwal).

Answer (score 0):

The anchorPoint has a value range of 0.0 to 1.0 (0% to 100%). If the anchorPoint is 0.5x0.5 (the default for nodes with textures) then the texture is centered on the node's position. If the anchorPoint is 0x0, then the texture's lower left corner aligns with the node's position. If the anchorPoint is 1x1 then the texture's upper right corner aligns with the node's position. This makes anchorPoint most popular when it comes to left, right, top or bottom align nodes. It is most often used to align text labels or to align screen elements with screen borders. Here are some examples:

[image]

Comment: If you want more information and example here is the link for your reference :
http://www.garethelms.org/2014/06/help-with-spritekit-position-and-anchorpoint/